# assigning current values towards function for energetics

Tags: r

Good afternoon all.

I have a simple hypothetical dataset of 2 male runners, both weigh 70kg and have 100,000 kcal of energy available. Both runners ran a 13 day race with varying daily distances (km).

Because cost of locomotion declines as one loses mass, I need to recalculate energy expended based on body mass at the end of the previous day.

For example, 70 kg runner loses 0.5 kg during day 1. The runner now weighs 69.5 kg and will have a different rate of energy expenditure during day 2.

Here's the data - I manually entered expected values for the first 2 days of each runner.

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("Male1", "Male2"), class = "factor"), Day = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L), Km = c(7L, 9L, 15L, 
11L, 5L, 15L, 25L, 15L, 12L, 11L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 
15L, 9L, 15L, 12L, 1L, 25L, 2L, 3L, 14L), Kcal = c(328.91, 410.24, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 46.99, 93.97, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), NewMass = c(66.96, 66.91, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 69.995, 69.984, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("ID", "Day", 
"Km", "Kcal", "NewMass"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-26L))
```

I first defined a function for the cost of locomotion (kcal/kg)

```
costkm <- function(kg) {
  (2.57 * (kg ^ -0.316)) * kg #formula to calculate cost of locomotion
}
```

Then I tried to write code for each individual (ID) and each day run (nrow)
followed by distance (KM) ran during each day for both runners times the locomotion formula followed by code for updated mass at end of the day (9,000 kcal per kg). I cannot "visualize" how to structure the codes...any help would be appreciated!

```
for (i in unique (df$ID)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(i))
    df$Kcal<-df$Km * costkm #calculate kcal expended based on current weight
    NewMass<- lag(NewMass) - (Kcal/9000) #calculate updated mass
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use `split` to divide up your dataframe into two dataframes (one for each runner):

```
dfs <- split(df, df$ID)
```

which gives you a list with two elements:

```
str(dfs)
# $ Male1:'data.frame': 13 obs. of  5 variables:
#   ..$ ID     : Factor w/ 2 levels "Male1","Male2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#   ..$ Day    : int [1:13] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#   ..$ Km     : int [1:13] 7 9 15 11 5 15 25 15 12 11 ...
#   ..$ Kcal   : num [1:13] 329 410 NA NA NA ...
#   ..$ NewMass: num [1:13] 67 66.9 NA NA NA ...
#  $ Male2:'data.frame':  13 obs. of  5 variables:
#   ..$ ID     : Factor w/ 2 levels "Male1","Male2": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
#   ..$ Day    : int [1:13] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#   ..$ Km     : int [1:13] 1 2 6 8 15 9 15 12 1 25 ...
#   ..$ Kcal   : num [1:13] 47 94 NA NA NA ...
#   ..$ NewMass: num [1:13] 70 70 NA NA NA ...
```

Now, you can use `lapply` to iterate through the list, and iterate through the rows for each dataframe:

```
output <- lapply(dfs, function(df) {
  for (i in 2:nrow(df)) {
    df$Kcal[i] <- df$Km[i] * costkm(df$NewMass[i - 1])
    df$NewMass[i] <- df$NewMass[i - 1] - (df$Kcal[i] / 9000)
  }
  return(df)
})
output <- do.call(rbind, output) # Bind the dataframes together again
```

This gives you

```
output
#             ID Day Km       Kcal  NewMass
# Male1.1  Male1   1  7  328.91000 66.96000
# Male1.2  Male1   2  9  410.23565 66.91442
# Male1.3  Male1   3 15  683.40769 66.83848
# <snip>
# Male2.14 Male2   1  1   46.99000 69.99500
# Male2.15 Male2   2  2   93.96994 69.98456
# Male2.16 Male2   3  6  281.88106 69.95324
# <snip>
```

Comment: Thank you Weihuang.